# Debugging slow Postgresql 9.3 COMMITs

Tags: postgresql

With slow query logging turned on, we see a lot of `COMMIT`s taking upwards of multiple seconds to complete on our production database. On investigation, these are generally simple transactions: fetch a row, `UPDATE` the row, `COMMIT`. The `SELECT`s and `UPDATE`s in these particular transactions aren't being logged as slow. Is there anything we can do, or tools that we can use, to figure out the reason for these slow commits? We're running on an SSD, and are streaming to a slave, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Streaming to replica might make a big difference. Is synchronous replication enabled? If so, that can easily cause delayed commits. You can confirm this is the cause by temporarily disabling synchronous replication (setting `synchronous_standby_names = ''` or setting `synchronous_commit = 'local'`)

Comment: Both those settings are set to the default, which as I understand the docs, mean that synchronous_commit is effectively 'local' already.

Comment: Try `log_lock_waits=true` to see if your writes are contended.

Comment: log_lock_waits is on, with deadlock_timeout = 1s. Lock delays are being logged, but there's no apparent relation to the slow commits.

Comment: Any deferred constraints/triggers? Can't think of much else which would be happening during a commit other than the flush to disk, and presumably you don't want to experiment with `fsync=off` in production. Have you looked for potential I/O issues?

Comment: We have no constraints and no triggers. I'd rather not turn fsync off. How would I investigate potential I/O issues? This is running on a linode instance, for what it's worth.

Comment: Not really my area, but I think you'd start by logging the output of something like `iotop` and checking the write throughputs and IO waits around the time of the slow commit. If it is a slow fsync, [`pg_test_fsync`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtestfsync.html) should be able to reproduce it, but if it's an intermittent issue it might be hard to catch in the act, and it's certainly not going to help your `COMMIT` times while it's running...

Comment: Tools like `glances` can help you monitoring resources consumption in real-time: RAM, IO-Waits, CPU, IO speeds, etc. Install it via `apt install glances` and run it using `glances -t 1` for 1 second update interval. If you see high percentages of IO-Waits then you are IO bound. Take a look also at swap usage: maybe you are RAM bound.

Comment: Please provide some more information like checkpoint settings and wal settings

Comment: No constraints at all? Not even a primary key? If so.. table locks would be a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming to a slave creates additional IO on commits. Depending on where your slave is located and how it's configured, you may need to optimize your network, get a faster drive, or take other actions to improve the throughput on the slave device. For a test, you could disable the slave (preferably on a test server of some kind) to see how it performs with the slave enabled and disabled.

Secondly, check for any "after" triggers on the tables being updated.
Third, check for any deferred constraints on the tables being updated.

Those last two will create additional overhead upon commit.

Answer (score -1):

Postgres commits are synchronous. This means they will wait for the WAL writes to complete before moving to the next one. You can adjust the WAL settings in the config file to adjust for this.

You can set the commit level to asynchronous at a session/user level or database wide with the synchronous_commit in the config file.

On the database side.

Vacuum your tables an update the statistics. This will get rid of dead tuples since your performing updates, there will be many.

```
VACUUM ANALYZE
```

Comment: slow commits should not be affected by `VACUUM` or boosted in the most cases. Also, disable `synchronous_commit` in a production database is not something someone would do.